# how to get title of a link tag using php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the title (or name?) of a link in PHP. Say I have link like this:

```
<a href="example.php">This is title</a>
```

When I click on this link , It'll takes me to example.php,
in that page I want to get that "This is title"

How can I do that in PHP or JavaScript or...?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Set the title of the next page with that link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="example.php?title=xyz">xyz</a>
```

Then access $_GET['title'];

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it from, "that page." You'll need to pass it along in the Query String as an alternate solution. You'll then be able to read it from "that page" ...

```
<a href="example.php?title=This%20is%20Title">This is title</a>
```

Then read it through PHP:

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
```

Comment: DOWNVOTE!? CARE TO EXPLAIN?!

Comment: Please not that using get will allow other users to manipulate that data. I could go to your site and go to the link: `example.php?title=MY%20TITLE` and the PHP will get `MY TITLE` instead of what you wanted. So make sure you are aware of this. @Xander and @xe4me

Comment: @EliteGamer you're right, but this is only solution that comes to my mind.

Comment: @elitegamer yes, i'm aware that anyone can modify a query string param. i present this as an alternative. if the inegrity of the value he's/she's passing is important - another approach would be prudent.

Comment: @MichałGrabowski Yes, that is perfectly fine. Basically, without knowing what he will do with this, i can not really tell him it is alright. He might be adding that to a database directly for all i know.

Comment: oh,
this title I'm tring to get is jist a time, such as: 9-10 AM, When a customer clicks on the link, the goal is to book 9-10AM for him/her and nothing else, still think its dangerous?

Comment: Nope. Thanks for the info though. You can not trust user input. I wish we all could though ;)

Comment: nope, it's common to pass that around. if the user changes that value in the title bar (or in the source of the href). they either, change their time to another or cause a type casting exception on the server when you try to read a value that isn't supported. this is fine, just use proper error handling and parameter sanitation.

Comment: It's a thinky :D, now you guys made me to think exactly what Im going to do , couse that time(9-10AM) is a doctor avalability to book , and every one has a profile , and if one of them manupulate that time like Elite Gamer said, ofcourse that'll couse many problem in my database

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many anchor tags you're going to have in the document. I suggest you give it an id or a class, but if it's the ONLY anchor, you can select by tag name.

```
var derp = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; //returns an array!!!
console.log(derp.innerHTML);
```

The link text does not transfer to the PHP page, so you will not be able to access it cross-pages.

Comment: I think this is useful. If we add the code to check if anhor is active (eg. comparing the urls), we can get it to work flawlessly.

Comment: Aha, thanks, although I didn't totally get the soloution you said, but I'll think it through

Comment: @xe4me basically, you can 1. find an anhor whose href url equals current url. If so -> get the title/text. Relatively slow way, but worth considering in terms of data security.

Comment: Just guessing, but the downvote may be due to the typo: you wrote "derp.innertHTML" which obviously has one "t" too many. Nonetheless, downvotes with no explination suck!

Comment: If somebody downvoted because of a typo, that's just wrong. lol It's fixed anyways